# Can i convert Angular 8 web application to ionic 4 app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I have done a application in angular 8 and with the codeigniter as the backend technology . 
I want to know how can i convert it to the Ionic 4 app .

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of, is by using a new blank Ionic project.

Create the project with the command ionic start myApp blank. This will create everything that Ionic & Cordova needs. Then, copy your files into this project manually. Since Ionic uses Angular, you should not have to make major changes.

Answer (score 0):

style files and major logics are reusable from the existing angular project, but the ui frameworks and tags are different, no convertor is available for now I think